# CSS resize images

Tags: html, image, resize, zooming, scale

What should I add to the CSS to make all images twice as large? It has to work in Firefox 12. I don't care about the visual quality degradation. The HTML contains the images like this: `<img src="foo.png">`. All images have different widths and heights, and I want to scale them proportionally: 200% width and 200% height.

I know that I can use an image converter to make the PNGs larger. However, in this question I'm interested in a CSS-only solution.

I know that I could add twice as large `width=... height=...` to the `<img` tags, but that would need a modification of the HTML (plus an auto-detection of the existing image sizes), and in this question I'm interested in a CSS-only solution.

Comment: Unless you don't care about making the images cover the rest of the page (in which case, use `-moz-transform: scale(2);`), it's simply not possible without JavaScript.

Comment: Using CSS here has the same problem as using HTML attributes, in that you first have to figure out what the original images size is in pixels. Unless you use `zoom` and do not care for browsers  that don't support it. (That is, Firefox is out.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible in a cross-browser way using CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just add:

```
img {max-width:200%;}
```

to your CSS?

This would be "adaptive," (or is that "responsive?") and would not "force" images to 200% (width), but would allow them to scale, up to and including 200% width, if the viewport is wide enough.

You could remove `max-` and explicitly "force" the 200% width, which will cause horizontal scroll-bars, if the viewport isn't wide enough.

As i understand it, choosing one or the other (`height` OR `width`, but not both), retains ratio.

You can style the `<img>` element directly in CSS, which should apply to all images in your HTML document, displayed via the `<img>` tag.

You could specify:

```
img {width:200%;}
```

If you want them to be "200% no matter what."

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately your suggestions don't work, because `200%` there means `200%` of the container element (e.g. `<body>`), not the `<img>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following css3:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-moz-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
```

Although, the image will be laid out as if it is taking up 100% space (like position:relative;).

Answer (score 0):

Enable JQuery working in the head section of your page.

```
<img src="foo.png" ID='scalable'>

$("#scalable").css("width", "200%");
$("#scalable").css("height", "200%");
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to think about my question and for submitting an answer. Unfortunately, this is not a working answer to my question, because it needs JavaScript, and I was asking for a CSS-only solution.